# PHP - Azure Table Storage in with more than 1000 entities

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to query from my table storage by using the Azure SDK for PHP.

My query looks like:

```
    $tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($this->connectionString);
    $filter = "( PartitionKey eq '$id' )";

    $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
    $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter));

    $result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities('test', $options);
    $entities = $result->getEntities();

    $nextPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
    $nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey();

    while (!is_null($nextRowKey) && !is_null($nextPartitionKey) ) {

        $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
        $options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPartitionKey);
        $options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey);
        $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter));

        $result2 = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("test", $options);
        $newentities = $result2->getEntities();
        $entities=array_merge($newentities, $entities);    

    }
```

The issue: When running into the while loop I always get the first 1000 back entities, with the same nextrowkey and nextpartitionkey for each query. Thus it creates an infinit loop.

What am I getting wrong with the continuation of a query?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gaurav: this is true, but occurs only on the second loop (I forgot to add the two lines when posting my code).

I've been trying to find out what's wrong for at least half a day. Finally I got it:
It is due to an older version of the Windows Azure PHP SDK which has a "bug". I stumbled across this "bug" at the bottom of this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/702
The older version of Windows Azure SDK uses _encodeODataUriValue which seems to be unnecessary.