# how to retrive more than 1000 rows in azure tables php

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to get more than 1000 rows from azure in php.
First of all i am not able to use filter class. which namespace need to be added to use filter class
after that while loop is gng in infinite loop
any help

$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($this->connectionString);
    $filter = "( PartitionKey eq '$id' )";

```
$options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
$options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter));

$result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities('test', $options);
$entities = $result->getEntities();

$nextPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
$nextRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey();

while (!is_null($nextRowKey) && !is_null($nextPartitionKey) ) {

    $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
    $options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPartitionKey);
    $options->setNextRowKey($nextRowKey);
    $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter));

    $result2 = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("test", $options);
    $newentities = $result2->getEntities();
    $entities=array_merge($newentities, $entities);    

}
```

link m using is
[PHP - Azure Table Storage in with more than 1000 entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177787/php-azure-table-storage-in-with-more-than-1000-entities)

Comment: Any update for now?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [`setTop()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesOptions.php#L177) function of `MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\QueryEntitiesOptions` class to select the top X (number) entities of the table.

And according the description at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesOptions.php#L148, we can find that the filter classes have moved into the `namespace MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\Filters`

If you want to use the filter classes in the new Azure Storage SDK for PHP, you can try to include the package as:

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\Filters\QueryStringFilter;
```

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\QueryEntitiesOptions;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\Filters\QueryStringFilter;
$options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
$filter = new QueryStringFilter("(RowKey eq '".$id."')");
$options->setFilter($filter);
$options->setTop(1000);
```